# Android Wear 1.5 wrist gesture API?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wake-lock

How to capture the android wear tilt event that is used to wake even when the screen is on?

```
 @Override
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_WAKEUP)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wake up event called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("jts","    keyevent for wakeup called");
    }

    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wake up event called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("jts"," keyevent for power called");
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"key event called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("jts", " keyevent called  " + event );
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `KEYCODE_WAKEUP`:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_WAKEUP

Comment: I am trying to catch this event using dispatchkeyevent(), and i am not getting this event

Comment: I am getting navigation up and navigation down event. But not wake event